# Hidden overflow and sticky elements

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent horizontal overflow for the body of the page and allow sticky elements at the same time. The solution seems simple at a first glance:

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Everything works as expected on desktop. If you test it on mobile devices or choose a mobile device in Chrome dev tools, this will fail to work though. Apparantly, because touch devices ignore `overflow-x: hidden` for `html` and `body` tags as it's pointed out in many answers here on SO. So we have to use this instead:

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, this breaks sticky positioning. I know specifying the body height explicitely should fix the issue:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Voila, everything seems to work well on mobile and desktop devices. However, this breaks `window.onscroll` event because it's the body that is scrolling now. So most of the scroll dependant libraries will fail to work (e.g. AOS). I kind of gave up at this point. Anybody has a solution to this? I'd love to avoid JavaScript solutions if possible.

Comment: First thought that comes to mind is to find the element you have that causes the side scroll. Or is there any other reason you like to disable it?